# Assign a Date variable in SSIS Script Componentt

Tags: c#, datetime, ssis

In my script component, I am trying to assign a value to a `Date` column (the datatype is `DT_DATE`). These are `DateTime` objects in C#, so I thought the following would work:

```
FooBuffer.Datevar = DateTime.Now;
```

It compiles, but the line gives an error at runtime:

```
Error: 0xC020901C at FoobarFlow, OLE DB Destination [77]: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Datevar] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
```

My guess is that, since the `DateTime` class in C# is designed to have precision up to seconds (or even milliseconds -- not sure), and `DT_DATE`'s precision only goes up to days, there would be a possible loss of information.

So the question is, how do I assign such a column's value correctly? Is there any way to convert `DateTime` object to a `Date` before assigning it?

Comment: Have you tried DateTime.Today perchance?  This returns the date component with no time element (time of 00:00:00)

Comment: @DavidW: This is just sample code. In my actual code, I am assigning entirely different dates. :) Using the `DateTime.Date` property does not help, for the record.

Comment: Well, I am making a guess that the milliseconds portion of 'now' is what's causing grief. Try creating a new DateTime object with just the date and time components, but omitting the milliseconds, something like 'new DateTime(newDate.Year, newDate.Month,newDate.Day,newDate.Hour,newDate.Minute,newDate.Second);'

Comment: I'd like to have this question (which I posted myself) closed, since I resolved the error. It was something very obscure and localized, and the resolution will be of no use to anyone in the future.

Comment: Then  just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a DateTime value in an arbitrarily named variable `newDate`, try the following:

```
FooBuffer.DateVar = new DateTime(newDate.Year,
                                 newDate.Month,
                                 newDate.Day,
                                 newDate.Hour,
                                 newDate.Minute,
                                 newDate.Second);
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now contains more precision than DT_DATE is capable of storing.  Try this instead.

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```